# Not able to create instance of object

Tags: object, gnu-smalltalk

I am just starting to use gnu-smalltalk. I have taken following code from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/New-kinds-of-Numbers.html#New-kinds-of-Numbers) to define a class:

```
Number subclass: Complex [
       | realpart imagpart |
       "This is a quick way to define class-side methods."
       Complex class >> new [
           <category: 'instance creation'>
           ^self error: 'use real:imaginary:'
       ]
       Complex class >> new: ignore [
           <category: 'instance creation'>
           ^self new
       ]
       Complex class >> real: r imaginary: i [
           <category: 'instance creation'>
           ^(super new) setReal: r setImag: i
       ]
       setReal: r setImag: i [ "What is this method with 2 names?"
           <category: 'basic'>
           realpart := r.
           imagpart := i.
           ^self
       ]
   ]
```

However, I am not able to create any instances of this class. I have tried various methods and following gives least error!

```
cn := Complex new: real:15 imaginary:25
cn printNl
```

The error is:

```
complexNumber.st:24: expected object
```

Mostly the error is as follows, e.g. if there is no colon after `new` keyword:

```
$ gst complexNumber.st
Object: Complex error: use real:imaginary:
Error(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Error(Exception)>>signal: (ExcHandling.st:264)
Complex class(Object)>>error: (SysExcept.st:1456)
Complex class>>new (complexNumber.st:7)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (complexNumber.st:25)
nil
```

Also, I am not clear what is this method with 2 names, each with one argument:

```
setReal: r setImag: i [  "How can there be 2 names and arguments for one method/function?"
    <category: 'basic'>
    realpart := r.
    imagpart := i.
    ^self
]
```

I believe usual method should be with one name and argument(s), as from code [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Moving-money-around.html#Moving-money-around) :

```
   spend: amount [
       <category: 'moving money'>
       balance := balance - amount
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the `Complex` number `25 + 25i` evaluate

```
Complex real: 25 imaginary: 25
```

How do I know? Because the first part of your question reads

```
Complex class >> real: r imaginary: i [
       <category: 'instance creation'>
       ^(super new) setReal: r setImag: i
   ]
```

Your mistake was to write `Complex new: real: 25 imaginary: 25`, which doesn't conform to the Smalltalk syntax.

The Smalltalk syntax for a message with, say, 2 (or more) arguments consists of 2 (or more) keywords, ending with colon, followed, each of them, by the corresponding argument.

For example, the method `setReal: r setImag: i` has two keywords, namely `setReal:` and `setImag:` and receives two arguments `r` and `i`. The *name* of the method, which in Smalltalk is called its *selector* is the `Symbol` that results from concatenating the keywords, in this case `setReal:setImag:`.

Comment: So, `new` keyword is needed if the constructor does not have any arguments, otherwise arguments need to be sent and not `new` keyword.

Comment: Yes. When you create an instance of the class with `#new`, it will typically have `nil` in all its instance variables. For example `Complex new` would give you a complex number with `nil` as its real and imaginary parts, which doesn't make a lot of sense. That's why `Complex` provides the class method `real:imaginary:`, to give you a chance to create an initialized instance.

Comment: Thanks. I have another simple question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931290/can-one-create-a-standalone-method-function-without-any-class