# Can one create a standalone method/function (without any class)

Tags: smalltalk

I am trying to understand smalltalk. Is it possible to have a standalone method/function, which is not part of any particular class, and which can be called later:

```
amethod ['amethod called' printNl]. 
amethod.
```

Above code gives following error:

```
simpleclass.st:1: expected Eval, Namespace or class definition
```

How can I use `Eval` or `Namespace` as being suggested by error message?

I tried following but none work:

```
Eval amethod [...
amethod Eval [...
Eval amethod Eval[...        "!"
```

`Eval [...`  works but I want to give a name to the block so that I can call it later.

Following also works but gets executed immediately and does not execute when called later.

```
Namespace current: amethod ['amethod called' printNl].
```

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Smalltalk the equivalent to a standalone method is a `Block` (a.k.a. `BlockClosure`). You create them by enclosing Smalltalk expressions between square brackets. For example

```
[3 + 4]
```

To evaluate a block, you send it the message `value`:

```
[3 + 4] value
```

which will answer with `7`.

Blocks may also have arguments:

```
[:s | 3 + s]
```

you evaluate them with `value:`

```
[:s | 3 + s] value: 4  "answers with 7"
```

If the block has several sentences, you separate them with a dot, as you would do in the body of a method.

---

### Addendum

Blocks in Smalltalk are first class objects. In particular, one can reference them with variables, the same one does with any other objects:

```
three := 3.
threePlus := [:s | three + s].
```

for later use

```
threePlus value: 4    "7"
```

Blocks can be nested:

```
random := Random new.
compare := [:p :u | u <= p]
bernoulli60 := [compare value: 0.6 value: random next].
```

Then the sequence:

```
bernoulli60 value.  "true"
bernoulli60 value.  "false"
...
bernoulli60 value.  "true"
```

will answer with `true` about 60% of the times.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Can I give a name to this block so that I can call it later? Also, can there be arguments which I can send to this block with its name (like a regular function in python).

Comment: In Smalltalk all method should bu grouped within classes. No class - No method.

Comment: @rnso: "Can I give a name to this block so that I can call it later?" – Smalltalk has something called "variables". You can assign an object to a variable, which will allow you to refer to it using the name of the variable.

Comment: @rnso: "Also, can there be arguments which I can send to this block with its name" – Yes, see the paragraph starting with "Blocks may also have arguments" in [Leandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931482/2988).

Comment: I get it. It works. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: To expand on @JörgWMittag's response and use Leandro's example, you can do things like `addThreeBlock := [:summand | summand + 3]` to assign the block to a variable and then later call `addThreeBlock value: 4` to evaluate it (i.e. to add 3 to your argument).

Answer (score 2):

Leandro's answer, altough being correct and with deep smalltalk understanding, is answering what you asked for, but I think, not 100% sure thou, you are actually asking how to "play" around with a code without the need to create a class.

In my eyes want you want is called a *Workspace* (Smalltalk/X and Dolphin) (it can have different names like `Playground` in Pharo Smalltalk).

If you want to play around you need to create a local variable.

```
| result |

result := 0. "Init otherwise nil"

"Adding results of a simple integer factorial"
1 to: 10 do: [ :integer |
     result := result + integer factorial
].

Transcript show: result.
```

Explanation:

I'm using a `do:` block for `1-10` iterration. (`:integer` is a block local variable). Next I'm, showing the result on `Transcript`.